# Swift: How to make a change to a variable load next time the application is opened

Tags: ios, swift

I have some global settings variables that are occasionally changed by the user during the apps runtime. I want to make the users change permanent, but at the moment every time the app is then reloaded it reverts to the original values e.g. user changes SettingsVariables.settingTwo to false, but then when the app is rerun the variables value changes back to true (the original value).

```
import UIKit

struct SettingsVariables {

static var settingOne = 0
static var settingTwo = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create `UserDefaults` values these will be in the memory even when you close and restart your app.

```
// Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(123, forKey: "key")
// Get
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "key")
```

So basically you could do this in your `AppDeletegates` `applicationWillTerminate`.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(SettingsVariables.settingOne, forKey: "settingOne")
```

and then when your app start again you can do

`SettingsVariables.settingOne = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "settingOne")`

If you want to use your `Struct`.

**Update**
For Swift 2 as you are using, the syntax is this:

```
// Set
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(123, forKey: "key")
// Get
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. When I add this to the appdelegate it pops up with 'use of unresolved identifier UserDefaults. Is it meant to be NSUserDefaults instead? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Swift 2 or Swift 3?

Comment: ah... swift 2 currently

Comment: In fact you don't need UserDefaults at all to implement this kind of behaviour. Have a look at the answer below ;)

Comment: You should not rely on applicationWillTerminate method, it is not guaranteed that it will be called. For example if your app crashes for some reason, you will start from wrong values intead of the defaults, as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a dedicated struct with default values:

```
struct SettingsDefaults {
    static let settingOneDefault = 0
    static let settingTwoDefault = true
}
```

And Settings struct, which is initialized with defaults values, but is editable unlike SettingsDefaults.

```
struct Settings {
    static var settingOne = SettingsDefaults.settingOneDefault
    static var settingTwo = SettingsDefaults.settingTwoDefault
}
```

Just work with Settings struct across your app. It will get initialized only once.